# How can I select only the first occurance of a specific character using regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++, posix

I'm trying to match only the `T` character in the string below, which is between the date and timestamp.

```
"2016-04-28T13:57:02","3055551269","Incoming","Text","0.0"
```

I can find the grouping of numbers, with the `T` in the middle using \d[T]\d, but I can't seem to figure out how to capture only the first instance of `T`

Essentially, I'm trying to replace this character with a `,` in Notepadd++ to properly format a CSV file.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negated character class for this. Use this regex to search:

```
^([^T]*)T
```

And for replace use:

```
\1,
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ7oC4/2)

Comment: For replace, you probably want \1"," instead so that your first and second columns will still be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
      ^([^T]*)T
```

What it means is:-

From the start of String , don't include word until first T comes.

[^T] means do not include T

'*' means zero or more occurrences.

T means first occurace of T